# How do set text line height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design

So in Material Design Spec under Onboarding: [here](https://material.io/design/communication/onboarding.html#specs)

It is specified that:

> 32sp line height

which is the height from the bottom of the headline text to the base line of the subhead text.

My question is how exactly can this be implemented in flutter. Are padding enough to mimic this spec? or are there other more accurate ways to do this?

[image: Here]

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Yes, there is also a `height` property in `TextStyle` which allows you to manually adjust the height of the line.

Code Snippet

```
Text('Hey There', 
  style: TextStyle(height: 5, fontSize: 10),
)
```

[image]

Comment: How exactly is this computed? Like for the on above how to have 32sp exactly?

Comment: from my observaions `height` does not define the height between lines. Instead it defines the height of the drawable area for the text. That means that if it's too small then letters are cropped.

Answer (score 98):

In addition to Ayush's answer. If we look to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html), we can see

`When height is non-null, the line height of the span of text will be a multiple of fontSize and be exactly fontSize * height logical pixels tall.`

For example, if want to have height 24.0, with font-size 20.0, we should have height property 1.2

Example:

```
TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      height: 1.2,
);
```