# How to add space between words on separate lines in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: UI]

I want to add space between "Radio Frequency" and "Propagation" vertically i.e something like margin. and also make sure that text does not cut from top or bottom if I increase the font size.

Below is my code, I tried with spacing of letters, words and also decoration param but it did not get desired results. Thank you for your patience :)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      childAspectRatio: 1.5,
      mainAxisSpacing: 30,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(
        12,
        (index) {
          return Center(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 1,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/icons/radar_icon.png',
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    radius: 30,
                  )),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    "Radio Frequency Propagation",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14,height: 0.8),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ));
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do set text line height in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156806/how-do-set-text-line-height-in-flutter)

Comment: Increasing the height parameter from 0.8 to more should increase the space between the lines. Did you do that already? Did I understand the goal correctly?

Comment: @JigarPatel yes you understood the question, however, if I change that height the word propagation moves inside "Radio Frequency"

Comment: @FadyAdal I had tried playing with different combinations it did not work.

Comment: @Swapnil if it is a fixed text and you always want it to display as 2 lines, you can add a _\n_ inside the text itself. "Radio Frequency\nPropagation".

Comment: @JigarPatel sadly no, it will be dynamic text and this is one of the use case. And also I had tried using \n not a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `height` is correct. But I think the problem is the placement of the `style` parameters.

It should be like this:

```
Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    "Radio Frequency \nPropagation",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black87, 
                        fontSize: 14,
                      height: 1.5,
                      ),
                     ),
                    ),
                   );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this does not work though.