# Flutter: why Container is not taking size of text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have whole width as color background so I have taken `Container` for that and given width as `double.infinity` but it is not taking `height` of text inside it.

code,

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: width * 0.013,
              ),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 50,
                  fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
```

output I'm getting,

[image]

required output,

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156806/how-do-set-text-line-height-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

The container is taking the height of the text. The text height is calculated by the line height + font size.

So to get the height required set the line height to 1. You might have to go lower depending on the font.