# Vertical alignment of flutter text

Tags: flutter, fonts, vertical-alignment

Hi all I am trying to add a custom font 'Gill Sans' to my mobile app. However when I try and align an icon/ icon button and text on the same line they seem to look very out of alignment. It seems that this font is giving trouble the default flutter font has the correct alignment.

Does anyone know how I can correct the alignment? Thanks

This is what it is currently looking like, seems like the text is sitting too much towards the top.

[image: Image of alignment incorrect]

This is what it looks like with the standard flutter font and how I would like the alignment to look like:

[image: Image of desired alignment]

Here is a link to the font I am using. Gill Sans regular:

https://www.fontles.com/download/gill-sans-font/

Here is a snapshot of my code, using a simple list tile:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: App()));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Playground"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: const ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        minLeadingWidth: 0,
        title: Text(
          "Hello World",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Calibri",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem before, you could try to add `style` property inside the Text widget and add TextStyle with `height` property 1

```
const Text(
    "Hello World",
    style: TextStyle(height: 1),
)
```

You may want to check this one: [How do set text line height in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156806/how-do-set-text-line-height-in-flutter)

Comment: I did try this, seems like it moves other elements out of the way as it increases the size of the line i think. I have come up with a work around which I do not like but it works for the time being, adding padding to the top of Text() widget EdgeInsets.only(top: 6)

Comment: As a temporary solution, I also like to use padding. But if you have more time to solve this problem, you can use the widget inspector to check where the real problem is. I suspect the problem is from the original height of the font

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // todo onTap
    },
    child: const Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.home),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Text(
          "Hello World",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Calibri",
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

check pubspec.yaml And use this code to identify the font to the application

```
  fonts:
    - family: poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
```

Comment: Is there a reason why OP should wrap the Row in a GestureDetector?